# Try to figure out how to show content based on window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im using JSON and passing data through the href tag and using a click event to show specific items from a product database. My question is that I have code in the script that assigns a unique window hash to each product. It takes the product name and strips the spaces.

How can I show the correct item on the page if the hash tag matches the item when linking from an external url?

For example, when one of the items is clicked on the page the url will show something like www.website.com#CherryTomatoes.

Obviously I cant link to this from another website because the hash only exists when the click event is fired. I want to be able to automatically show the correct item when using an external link. Below is my code hope someone can help me out with this!

```
 //display product category based on click
      $("#displayall").click(function(event){
         displayAll();
      });

      //display all products function 
      function displayAll() {
          var categoryImage = '';

          $.each(json, function (i, item) {

                     categoryImage += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">' + '<a href="#"' + 'class="showProduct"' + 'data-itempageurl="' + item.itemName + '"' + 'data-itemgmo="' + item.itemGMOFree + '"' + 'data-itembpa="' + item.itemBPAFree + '"' + 'data-itemgluten="' + item.itemGlutenFree + '"' + 'data-itemimage="' + item.imageURL + '"' + 'data-itemname="' + item.itemName + '"' + 'data-itemoz="' + item.itemPackSize + '"' + 'data-itemdescription="' + item.itemDescription + '"' + 'data-itemupc="' + item.itemFullUPC + '">' + '<img class="img-responsive img-hover productImagesCategory" src="' + item.imageURL + '">' + '<h3>' + item.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';

          });

          $('#imagesCategoryProducts').hide().html(categoryImage).fadeIn('slow');

          //show individual product function on click
          $(".showProduct").click(function(event){

             //hide all current products
             $('#productCategories').hide();

             //get passed data from other function
             var clickedItemName = '<h1>' + $(this).data('itemname') + '</h1>';
             var clickedItemUPC = $(this).data('itemupc');
             var clickedItemOZ = '<h2>' + $(this).data('itemoz') + '</h2>';
             var clickedItemDescription = '<p>' + $(this).data('itemdescription') + '</p>';
             var clickedItemImage = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" src="' + $(this).data('itemimage') + '">';
             var clickedItemGluten = $(this).data('itemgluten');
             var clickedItemBPA = $(this).data('itembpa');
             var clickedItemGMO = $(this).data('itemgmo');
             var clickedItemPageURL = $(this).data('itempageurl');

             //check if clicked data equals correct item
             $.each(json, function (i, item) {
               if (item.itemName === clickedItemName) {
                  clickedItemName 
               }
               if (item.itemFullUPC === clickedItemUPC) {
                  clickedItemUPC
               }
               if (item.itemPackSize === clickedItemOZ) {
                  clickedItemOZ
               }
               if (item.itemDescription === clickedItemDescription) {
                  clickedItemDescription
               }
               if (item.imageURL === clickedItemImage) {
                  clickedItemImage
               }
               if (item.itemGlutenFree === clickedItemGluten) {
                  clickedItemGluten
               }
               if (item.itemBPAFree === clickedItemBPA) {
                  clickedItemBPA
               }
               if (item.itemGMOFree === clickedItemGMO) {
                  clickedItemGMO
               }

               //assign window hash to each product
               if (item.itemName === clickedItemPageURL) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  clickedItemPageURL = clickedItemPageURL.replace(/\s/g, '');
                  window.location.hash = clickedItemPageURL; 
               }
             });

               //remove extra characters from UPC
               var originalUPC = clickedItemUPC;
               var strippedUPC = '<h2>' + originalUPC.slice(1, -1); + '</h2>';

               //show individual product information
               $('#productSocialShare').show();
               $('#individualProduct').show();
               $('#relatedProducts').show();   

               //append product information to appropriate DIV
               $('#productTitle').html(clickedItemName);
               $('#productUPC').html(strippedUPC);
               $('#productOZ').html(clickedItemOZ);
               $('#productDescription').html(clickedItemDescription);
               $('#productImage').html(clickedItemImage);

               //check if gluten free is true and show image
               if (clickedItemGluten == "Y") {
                   clickedItemGluten = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="../images/misc/gluten_free_test.jpg">';
                   $('#productGlutenFree').html(clickedItemGluten);
                   $('#productGlutenFree').show();
               } else { 
                   $('#productGlutenFree').hide();
               }

               //check if bpa free is true and show image
               if (clickedItemBPA == "Y") {
                   clickedItemBPA = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="../images/misc/bpa_free_test.jpg">';
                   $('#productBPAFree').html(clickedItemBPA);
                   $('#productBPAFree').show();
               } else { 
                   $('#productBPAFree').hide();
               }

               //check if gmo free is true and show image
               if (clickedItemGMO == "Y") {
                   clickedItemGMO = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="../images/misc/gmo_test.jpg">';
                   $('#productGMOFree').html(clickedItemGMO);
                   $('#productGMOFree').show();
               } else { 
                   $('#productGMOFree').hide();
               }

            });
          closeNav();
      }
```

Comment: You can use hash in external URL (try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102668/try-to-figure-out-how-to-show-content-based-on-window-location-hash#comment69409889_41102668), and then refresh your browser), but as soon as your page is loaded, you need to check if the location hash has a value. If so, perform logic to take that value and display appropriate item.

Comment: so i guess i have to put this code outside the click function?

Comment: I would suggest to make a separate function which reads the URL hash and displays the product as per it. Call this function in `$(document).ready()` so that it displays the product details on page load. Also you can call this function after you modify location hash when a product is selected.